# Blackberry application to establish an http connection

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i have been working on developing an blackberry application. as per now i want the application to connect to a local server on my network and fetch a file from that machine. i have been using the library given by a named blackberry developer Mr.peter strange....here is the link for the same  [Http connection through BIS-B](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-HTTP-Connection-code-and-BIS-B-Access/td-p/653175)

my requirement would be setting up connection to the local server using any transport mode but it should be able to render the text downloaded.

i tried using the demos provided by blackberry samples as it comes with the plugin for eclipse the http demo from those samples shows only trying to setup an http connection string and the networkapidemo sample shows diffrent http codes when the url is entered as desired.i am running all the applications on the simulator. i havent tried running any of my apps on the hardware

may i know why this problem arises of http codes....ill also want to know guidelines about how to set a simple http connection just to download a file(text file) from a local server.

I have tried many forums too. if anybody would have a look at it i would post it here.
Only a simple connection is becoming a headache!

anyways...waiting for replies..

thanx in advance guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter whether you want to communicate with local or remote server.

1) See the API docs on [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html). There are sample code in there.

2) Unfortunatelly, on BB you should be aware of Network Transports. Check [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/m-p/206243#M29104) to get all info you need on Network Transports.

UPDATE:

The second point explains an approach that will work on any OS. If you need an OS 5+ only approach, then check the [ConnectionFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html) API. ConnectionFactory [usage sapmles](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/package-summary.html).

Comment: i am using simulators which has os 5.0 and above.....the second points thread that you mentioned is not the one for os 5.0 and above

Comment: The second thread explains an approach that will work on any OS. If you need an OS 5+ only approach, then check the ConnectionFactory http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html ConnectionFactory usage - http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/package-summary.html BTW, in your question you said nothing about you need a solution for os 5.0 only.